# Converting a non-formatted float to a time stamp

Tags: pandas, time

I have a data frame that has a column with the following values:

```
time = [5.0, 504.0, 847.0, 11.0, 1247.0]
```

I want to convert to a time in the `%H%M` format.

I tried using `to_datetime` but had error codes based on `5.0` entries.

Comment: As the name suggests... a `datetime` needs a *DATE* AND *TIME*, you might have better luck with `pd.to_timedelta`... but have failed to provide us with any details. What is `5.0`? Is that 5 Hours? 5 Minutes? 5 Nanoseconds?

Comment: 5.0 is 5 am, 504.0 is 5:04, 847.0 is 8:47, 11.0 is 11:00, 1`247 is 12:47

Answer (score 1):

One option, convert to strings with leading zeros:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [5.0, 504.0, 847.0, 11.0, 1247.0]})

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype('Int64').apply('{:04d}'.format), format='%H%M', errors='coerce')
```

Output:

```
     time            datetime
0     5.0 1900-01-01 00:05:00
1   504.0 1900-01-01 05:04:00
2   847.0 1900-01-01 08:47:00
3    11.0 1900-01-01 00:11:00
4  1247.0 1900-01-01 12:47:00
5     NaN                 NaT
```

Other option, split the digits above/below 100 and compute the minutes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [5.0, 504.0, 847.0, 11.0, 1247.0]})

h,m = df['time'].divmod(100)
df['timedelta'] = pd.to_timedelta(h*60+m, unit='min')
```

Output:

```
     time         timedelta
0     5.0   0 days 00:05:00
1   504.0   0 days 05:04:00
2   847.0   0 days 08:47:00
3    11.0   0 days 00:11:00
4  1247.0   0 days 12:47:00
```

Comment: If your interpretation is correct, I'd be willing to bet that the reason they're appearing as floats is due to `NaN` rows, in which case `astype(int)` will fail~

Comment: @BeRT2me then `astype('Int64')` ;)

Comment: 5.0 is actually 5 am not 00:05:00. The actual column has over 50k entries so it is too large to fix them individually.

Comment: @FernandoAraiza please edit your question with the well formatted explicit output

Answer (score 0):

Do string formatting to format your stuff correctly...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [5.0, 504.0, 847.0, 11.0, 1247.0]})
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time.astype('Int64')
                                .astype(str)
                                .str.ljust(3, '0')
                                .str.zfill(4), format='%H%M').dt.time
```

Output:

```
     time timestamp
0     5.0  05:00:00
1   504.0  05:04:00
2   847.0  08:47:00
3    11.0  01:10:00
4  1247.0  12:47:00
```